# Is there is a good library in opencv for blob handling?

Tags: opencv

Is it better to implement blob(connected component) handling manually in openCV or are there any good libraries for the same? I found cvblob and cvBlobsLib? Are these libraries used on a standard scale?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Blob extraction in OpenCV](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4641817/blob-extraction-in-opencv)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also looked into this and decided in the end to write my own CCL routine. It seems like a serious omission from OpenCV and no doubt a lot of people are "reinventing the wheel" as a result. Note however that you may be able to use `findContours`, depending on your exact requirements - see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4641817/blob-extraction-in-opencv).

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at the new [opencvblobslib](https://code.google.com/p/opencvblobslib/). It has great features like multi core support.