# Javacv Blob detection

Tags: java, opencv, feature-detection, blobs, javacv

I would like to use some blob detection in my application which is written in Java and thus using `JavaCV` instead of `OpenCV`. I found many classes like:

`SimpleBlobDetector`, `CvBlobDetector`, `CvBlob`, ... but I can't find any tutorial or demo/example code to use these in Java.
Could anyone please tell me how to use these as I can't figure it out and there's no good documentation for them.
Thanks!

Comment: The JavaCV API maps as closely as possible the C/C++ API. If you can find some documentation or sample written in C/C++, it should not be too hard to translate that to Java...

Answer (score 8):

I am just in this moment working on the same problem and have a first solution.
There's a lot of approaches out there but unfortunately most of them are ugly and slow.
My main goal to this point was to stay in the JavaCV/OpenCV-World.

These Links pushed me in the right direction:

1. [Blob extraction in OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4641817/blob-extraction-in-opencv)
2. http://voices.yahoo.com/connected-components-using-opencv-5462975.html?cat=15
3. http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#cv-findcontours

Here's a complete Demo class that should show you how it's done.
Try it with a black background image with simple objects and sharp corners for best results. Make sure to check the second link above to get informed about what's happening in the code.

```
import static com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.sizeof;
import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.CV_FILLED;
import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.CV_RGB;
import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.IPL_DEPTH_8U;
import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.cvCreateImage;
import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.cvCreateMemStorage;
import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.cvDrawContours;
import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.cvGetSize;
import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.cvPoint;
import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_highgui.cvLoadImage;
import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_highgui.cvSaveImage;
import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_imgproc.CV_BGR2GRAY;
import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_imgproc.CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE;
import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_imgproc.CV_RETR_CCOMP;
import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_imgproc.CV_THRESH_BINARY;
import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_imgproc.cvCvtColor;
import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_imgproc.cvFindContours;
import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_imgproc.cvThreshold;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.util.Random;

import com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.CvContour;
import com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.CvMemStorage;
import com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.CvScalar;
import com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.CvSeq;
import com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.IplImage;

/**
 * A demo for blob extraction using only JavaCV / OpenCV
 * @see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4641817/blob-extraction-in-opencv
 * @see http://voices.yahoo.com/connected-components-using-opencv-5462975.html?cat=15
 * @see http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#cv-findcontours
 * @author happyburnout
 */

public class JavaCVBlobDemo {

    static String sourcePath = "c:/test/source.jpg";
    static String targetPath = "c:/test/target.jpg";

    public static void main (String args[]){
        IplImage image = cvLoadImage(sourcePath);
        IplImage grayImage = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(image), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
        cvCvtColor(image, grayImage, CV_BGR2GRAY);

        CvMemStorage mem;
        CvSeq contours = new CvSeq();
        CvSeq ptr = new CvSeq();
        cvThreshold(grayImage, grayImage, 150, 255, CV_THRESH_BINARY);
        mem = cvCreateMemStorage(0);

        cvFindContours(grayImage, mem, contours, sizeof(CvContour.class) , CV_RETR_CCOMP, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, cvPoint(0,0));

        Random rand = new Random();
        for (ptr = contours; ptr != null; ptr = ptr.h_next()) {
            Color randomColor = new Color(rand.nextFloat(), rand.nextFloat(), rand.nextFloat());
            CvScalar color = CV_RGB( randomColor.getRed(), randomColor.getGreen(), randomColor.getBlue());
            cvDrawContours(image, ptr, color, CV_RGB(0,0,0), -1, CV_FILLED, 8, cvPoint(0,0));
        }
        cvSaveImage(targetPath, image);
    }

}
```

Comment: please provide the sample image that you used in here. thanks

Comment: @SL_User: Please use the image provided in the second link above

Answer (score -2):

```
public static IplImage detectObjects(IplImage srcImage){

    IplImage resultImage = cvCloneImage(srcImage);

    CvMemStorage mem = CvMemStorage.create();
    CvSeq contours = new CvSeq();
    CvSeq ptr = new CvSeq();

    cvFindContours(srcImage, mem, contours, Loader.sizeof(CvContour.class) , CV_RETR_CCOMP, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, cvPoint(0,0));

    CvRect boundbox;

    for (ptr = contours; ptr != null; ptr = ptr.h_next()) {
        boundbox = cvBoundingRect(ptr, 0);

        cvRectangle( resultImage, cvPoint( boundbox.x(), boundbox.y() ), cvPoint( boundbox.x() + boundbox.width(), boundbox.y() + boundbox.height()),cvScalar( 0, 255, 255, 0 ), 3, 0, 0 ); 
    }

    return resultImage;
}
```

Comment: yep... 'box' should be replaced with 'boundbox'. What you really means by incomplete. This method is complete and it is working for me. Please comment what part will give errors.

Comment: cvRectangle( resultImage, cvPoint( box.x(), box.y() ), 
                  cvPoint( box.x() + box.width(), box.y() + box.height()), <- the line isn't even finished

Comment: Sorry for that i missed that part when i copied the code from project.

Comment: cvRectangle( resultImage, cvPoint( box.x(), box.y() ), cvPoint( box.x() + box.width(), box.y() + box.height()),cvScalar( 0, 255, 255, 0 ), 3, 0, 0 );

Comment: this is a code segment from my final year research project. This is working fine. SO if you have any problem with this code please let me know. thankx..

Comment: What is the "cvBoundingRect" method in this code. I can't find that method when I try to call it???

Comment: cvBoundingRect is a method that is available at `com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_imgproc`