# How to convert this code into javacv?

Tags: java, opencv, image-processing

I had went through many tutorials and guide lines and I was able to convert part of it. But I don't know how to convert last line in to javacv. So Please can some one help me to convert this code in to javacv?

```
img = cv2.imread('sofud.jpg')

gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(gray,127,255,1)

contours,hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_LIST,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

  for cnt in contours:
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
    if 10 < w/float(h) or w/float(h) < 0.1:
    cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,0,255),2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the last line as this in Java CV:

```
opencv_core.cvRectangle(image, opencv_core.cvPoint(m,n), opencv_core.cvPoint(i,j), opencv_core.cvScalar(0,0,255,0), thickness, 8, 0);
```

Where the parameters mean:

```
opencv_core.cvRectangle(CvArr* img, CvPoint , CvPoint, CvScalar color, int thickness=1, int lineType=8, int shift=0)
```

and look at this [Link](http://ganeshtiwaridotcomdotnp.blogspot.in/2012/04/colored-object-tracking-in-java-javacv.html#more) for more information.

**EDIT:**

This is an example of finding contours:

```
cvFindContours(grayImage, memory, contours, sizeof(CvContour.class) , CV_RETR_CCOMP, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, cvPoint(0,0));
```

Where the parameter mean:

```
cvFindContours(CvArr* image, CvMemStorage* storage, CvSeq** first_contour, int header_size=sizeof(CvContour), int mode=CV_RETR_LIST, int method=CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, CvPoint offset=cvPoint(0,0) )
```

For more information on the parameters, take a look at this [Link](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=findcontours#findcontours), under `FindContours` section.

You can also use the `cvDrawContours` function, to draw the contours in the same way as we have used `cvFindContours` function.

Take a look at this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9129037/javacv-blob-detection). It is a different post on this website in which the they have explained the use of finding contours in blob detection.

Hope This Helps.

Comment: Please can you also explain how to use "findContours" method in javacv. It take another 3 integer parameters what are those things ?

Comment: @LBNCons Please look at the "EDIT:" section in my answer above.