# Adding my own function to OpenCV

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opencv, cmake

I need to add a new method that computes connected components to OpenCV 2.4.4 to use in one of my own projects.  I already have the code for the function from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4641817/blob-extraction-in-opencv/10116591#10116591) (Thanks to [jason](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1327999/jason)), I navigated my way to [the patch](http://code.opencv.org/attachments/467/opencv-connectedcomponents.patch) where I found both the code and the header.

What I did was to add a new file `connectedcomponents.cpp` in `C:\opencv\modules\imgproc\src`, in which I placed the code for this new function.  Next, I went to `C:\opencv\modules\imgproc\include\opencv2\imgproc` and I added the appropriate export header to `imgproc.hpp`.  Finally, I rebuilt the `opencv_imgproc` project in the OpenCV source code using Visual Studio 2010.  Everything builds fine, and generates the `opencv_imgproc244.dll`, `opencv_imgproc244.lib`, and `opencv_imgproc244.exp` files for me.

Now, I copy these files (except for the .exp, where I can't find where it should go?) into my existing OpenCV directory and replace the old files.  When I now try to build my own project, everything still builds fine, but I cannot access the new method from here.  I include `#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>`, and from here I can access all the other methods in the file, except for the new one that I want.

The fact that everything compiles but that the method is not exposed leads me to think there is some other file that I should have changed as well, however, due to lack of experience I do not know where or what this file could be.

Extra information:
I am using Visual Studio 2010, OpenCV 2.4.4 and built OpenCV with CMake 2.8.10.2
I am aware that there are libaries such as [cvBlobsLib](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/cvBlobsLib) that compute connected components, and I have successfully used these in my project.  However, I want a faster and more recent solution (cvBlobsLib still uses the old IplImage).

Comment: Can you add a detailed tutorial on how you compiled OpenCV from source using cmake and visual studio 2010 ? Or atleast share a good reference which helped you. Mine always ends up in some errors.

Comment: did you flag your functions/definitions as CV_EXPORTS ?

Comment: @AbidRahmanK, I don't want to enter a discussion here, but my original build was some time ago, if I can find the link I will paste it.  @berak, Yes, I did it exactly the same as all the other questions in the `.hpp` file, I think it was `CV_EXPORTS_W`, but I did add it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after looking at the problem with a fresh pair of eyes this morning, I immediately spotted my mistake.  What I **originally did** was to add the new function's header code in

`C:\opencv\modules\imgproc\include\opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp`,

but what I **should've done** is to also add it to

`C:\opencv\build\include\opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp`,

because this is the file that is included by any project that uses OpenCV.  Everything works as planned now.